# Calculating dice probabilities with multiple, overlapping success criteria

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

Alright, so I play a tabletop game where models get in fights and roll dice to see if they deal damage to the other models. **I'm wondering how to calculate the probabilities of dealing 0, 1, and 2 damage in a 2v2 fight.**

Here is the situation:
- We have Model A and Model B rolling to deal damage to Model C and Model D
- A needs to roll a 5 or 6 to damage C, and a 6 to damage D
- B needs to roll a 4, 5, or 6 to damage C, and a 5 or 6 to damage D
- C and D can only be damaged once each (i.e., they die when they get damaged)

So for starters, I know the probabilities for this scenario just by listing out the possibilities:

```
  A | 111111 222222 333333 444444 555555 666666
  B | 123456 123456 123456 123456 123456 123456
----+------------------------------------------
Dmg | 000111 000111 000111 000111 111122 111222
```

So the probability of dealing 0 damage is $\frac{12}{36}$, (exactly) 1 damage is $\frac{19}{36}$, and 2 damage is $\frac{5}{36}$. One tricky outcome here is when A rolls a 5 and B rolls a 4. This only results in 1 damage since both rolls are only enough to damage C and C can only be damaged once.

I am hopelessly stumped on how to model this so that I can then apply it to other scenarios such as 3v3s or when some models use more than 1 die.

It is pretty easy to calculate the probabilities of doing damage in a 1v1 fight. I've used binomial distribution statistics to calculate those. Conveniently it works for multiple dice per model as well. However, when it comes to combining these probabilities ... I am at a loss. They don't seem to follow the rules for multiplication and addition.

For example, I naïvely expected the probability of doing 0 damage to be the probability of A doing 0 damage and the probability of B doing no damage. That sounds right intuitively, but no matter how I try to do it ... it never makes sense:

$ P(A\;miss\;C) = \binom{1}{0} \bullet 2^0 \bullet 4^1 = 4 $
$ P(A\;miss\;D) = \binom{1}{0} \bullet 1^0 \bullet 5^1 = 5 $
$ P(B\;miss\;C) = \binom{1}{0} \bullet 3^0 \bullet 3^1 = 3 $
$ P(B\;miss\;D) = \binom{1}{0} \bullet 2^0 \bullet 4^1 = 4 $

Therefore,

$ P(A\;miss\;C) \bigcap P(A\;miss\;D) \bigcap P(B\;miss\;C) \bigcap P(B\;miss\;D) = 4 \bullet 5 \bullet 3 \bullet 4 = 240 $

Wait what?!?! I expect the answer to be 12. Clearly there is something else going on here that I do not understand. :/

Comment: You can't say $\Pr(X\cap Y)=\Pr(X)\Pr(Y)$ unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent events, and these are clearly not.  When A doesn't damage C it's likely that he doesn't damage D, either, because he rolled a low number.

Comment: Also, you're multiplying counts instead of probabilities. The product of the probabilities (even if you could just multiply them, i.e. if they were independent, which they aren't) would be $\frac46\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac36\cdot\frac46=\frac{240}{6^4}=\frac5{27}\approx0.185$, which is at least a lot closer to the $\frac{12}{6^2}\approx0.333$ that you were apparently expecting than $\frac{240}{6^2}\approx6.67$ would have been.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to rephrase your question:

A and B each roll a die. The results of the die determine how much damage is dealt. The maximum{damage dealt by A, damage dealt by B} is the number we are interested in.

A Deals 1 damage by rolling a 5 or 2 damage by rolling a 6. B deals 1 damage by rolling a 4 or 2 damage by rolling a 5 or 6. Now take the maximum of the damage dealt by A or B.

---

I think it may be easier to frame it this way:

A misses and B Misses simultaneously:

P(0 Damage) = P(A Rolls 4 or less) * P(B rolls 3 or less) = 2/3*1/2= 1/3 = 3/9

A Hits both or B hits Both (don't double count):

P(2 Damage) = P(A Rolls 6) +  P(B Rolls 5 or 6) - P(A Rolls 6 AND B rolls 5 or 6) = 1/6 +  1/3 - 1/6*1/3 = 4/9

P(1 Damage) = 1-P(0)-P(2) = 2/9

---

Alternatively,

A hits 1 (rolls 5) or B hits 1 (rolls 4)

P(1 Damage) = P(B Rolls 4)*P(A Rolls 5 or less) + P(B Rolls 3 or less)*P(A Rolls 5) = 1/6*5/6+ 3/6*1/6= 2/9

How I verified my answer: The table below shows how much damage occurs when (A rolls, B rolls) happens. Count the number of 0s and divide by 36 to determine how often 0 damage occurs. Repeat for 1s and 2s.

---

### | x  | 1 | 2        | 3              | 4 | 5 | 6 |

### | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

### | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

### | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

### | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

### | 5 |  1 | $\text{ }$1 | 1 |$\text{ }$ 1 | 2 | 2 |

### | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

---

Summary:

P( 0 damage ) = 3/9

P( 1 damage ) = 2/9

P( 2 damage ) =  4/9